# How to Resolve Cors issue in chrome?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have a developed a website and.that i hosted Google firebase hosting.that website is working fine in some of countries like ( India, china,Netherlands).

when i access same website in UAE countries.i am getting errors [please check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxqcb.png)

I have added some Cors Extension also. but did not work.i have used firebase auth functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express you can try this:

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

Where app is the name of your express function.